# obtain the content of a line number 45 on a file, in the last profile connected on a remote position

Tags: powershell

I wish to set up a powershell script, which will allow to obtain the content of a line number 45 on a file, in the last profile connected on a remote position
the path in question is:
USERPROFILE \ AppData \ Roaming \ Avaya \ one-X Agent \ 2.5 \ Config.xml

the goal is to have the content of this line for several positions (around 500) in a computer park

this is the xml file :

```html
<ConfigData xmlns="http://xml.avaya.com/endpointAPI">
<version>1</version>
<parameter>
<name>OwnIPAddress</name>
<value>10.87.1.254</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>SipProxyServerList</name>
<value>10.69.76.10</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>AlternateServersList</name>
<value>10.69.76.10;</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>DialPlanCountryCode</name>
<value>
    </value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>DialPlanInternationalAccessCode</name>
<value>
    </value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>DialPlanLongDistanceAccessCode</name>
<value>
    </value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>DialPlanOutsideLineAccessCode</name>
<value>
    </value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>RtpPortLow</name>
<value>2048</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>RtpPortRange</name>
<value>63487</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>PrevSipUserAccount</name>
<value>2729350</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>AlternateServerListTimeOut</name>
<value>30</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>DialPlanNationalPhoneNumbLengthList</name>
<value>
    </value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>DialPlanExtensionLengthList</name>
<value>
    </value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>AlternateGKAddressList</name>
<value>10.69.76.10</value>
</parameter>
</ConfigData>
```

and i have found this command:

```
(Get-Content -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Roaming\Avaya\one-X Agent\2.5\Config.xml" -TotalCount 45)[-1]
```

Comment: It is *not* a good idea to directly peek (and/or poke) in a XML files, you should you [XML or XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xpath.asp) methods for that.

Comment: Please provide an example of the XML you want to amend, and what you have tried so far.

Comment: If you want to retrieve the value of `PrevSipUserAccount` (= `2729350`): `[Xml]$x = Get-Content .\YourFile.xml; $x.ConfigData.Parameter.Where{$_.Name -eq 'PrevSipUserAccount'}.Value`

Answer (score 0):

**The code below will find the value of the `PrevSipUserAccount` node.**
Note that this code may perform non-optimally on large XML files, and that `return` in Powershell functions doesn't perform the same way as `return` in languages such as C#.

```bsh
param(
    [string] $filepath = "$PSScriptRoot\Config.xml",
    [string] $targetParamName = 'PrevSipUserAccount'
)

[xml] $xml = Get-Content $filepath
$params = $xml.ConfigData.Parameter 

$obj = @{}
foreach ($param in $params) {    
    $obj = [PSCustomObject] @{
        Name = ($param | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name).Trim()
        Value = ($param | Select-Object -ExpandProperty value).Trim()    
    }
    if ($obj.Name.Contains("$targetParamName")) {
        return $obj
    }
}
```